# How to allow the user to zoom and rotate 3D objects in Opengl and Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, opengl, glut

I am new to opengl and visual c++. I have done a sample application which rotates 3D shapes in opengl. I want to allow the user to rotate and zoom the object. Please give me an example of how to do this.

I have tried NeHe tutorial: http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=48

I can't understand the class structure in the example. Is there anysimple way to achieve this?

I have found a library as well: http://www.nigels.com/glt/gltzpr/

But still can't figure out how to do this.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zooming is usually done through gluLookAt. The third parameter is the view distance.
Here is some basic example running this :

http://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs248-01/OpenGLHelpSession/code_example.html

Look in display() to see how the viewing distance is used and in MouseMotion() to see how the value is modified and the painting updated.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer Joel. But I can't run this example.

Comment: oh, it is maybe a bit old. Look up the doc for gluLookAt

Comment: ok. I will. Thanks. Is there a way to allow the user to rotate the object? I did not get any example yet. Please show me one.

Comment: Have a look at the Nehe openGL tutorials:
http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=10

Comment: @Joel Falcou: gluLookAt defines the viewpoint, i.e. you move around the camera with it. In a real camera the focal length is changed when zooming; this directly translates into the field of view of gluPerspective, or at constant limits the distance of the near clipping plane.